# Derivative of function with respect to multivariable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

Let 
\begin{align*}
  V\colon \mathbb R & \to \mathbb R \\
  x & \longmapsto
  V(x).
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
  w\colon \mathbb R^3 & \to \mathbb R \\
  (a,b,c) & \longmapsto
  w(a,b,c).
\end{align*}
I thought that using the chain rule we have $\dfrac{dV(w)}{dw(a,b,c)} = \dfrac{dV}{da} \dfrac{\partial a}{\partial w} + \dfrac{dV}{db} \dfrac{\partial b}{\partial w}+ \dfrac{dV}{dc} \dfrac{\partial c}{\partial w}$?

Numerically, I am finding that $\dfrac{dV(w)}{dw(a,b,c)} = \dfrac{1}{3}\cdot\left(\dfrac{dV}{da} \dfrac{\partial a}{\partial w} + \dfrac{dV}{db} \dfrac{\partial b}{\partial w}+ \dfrac{dV}{dc} \dfrac{\partial c}{\partial w}\right)$.

Which is correct? Why do I need multiply by $\dfrac{1}{3}$?

Comment: Your notation does not make any sense. $w$ is a function, so the first mapping is unclear.

Comment: What does it mean to differentiate with respect to a function?

Comment: @AndresMejia is it clear now? V is a function of w. And w is also a function

Comment: Are you trying to speak of things like change of coordinates, and differentiating with resepct to the new coordinates?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I don’t think so

Comment: You should then attempt to clarify what you mean by differentiating a function with respect to another function.

Comment: and indeed how $V$ has $\mathbb R$ as its domain

Comment: @AndresMejia V takes the output of w as an input

Comment: Then you need that $w$ is surjective, otherwise the notation is still unjustified. It also does not take the function as an input. It takes a real number *outputted* by $w$ as an input

Comment: @AndresMejia I tried to clean up the notation. Is it clearer now?

Comment: It still does not adress the fact that you are differentiating with respect to a function. Do you wish to calculate the Jacobian of $V\circ w$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f:A\longrightarrow B$. We denote the Jacobian of $f$ at $x\in A$ by $J_f(x)$.
The chain rule for the Jacobian is

$$J_{f\circ g}(x) =  J_f\big(g(x)\big)\cdot J_g(x).$$

Applying this to your case we have

$$J_{V\circ w}(a,b,c) =  J_V\big(w(a,b,c)\big)\cdot J_w(a,b,c).$$

Now, $V$ is a single variable function and hence $J_V\big(w(a,b,c)\big) =  V'\big(w(a,b,c)\big)$, where $V'$ is the usual derivative.

On the other hand, $w:\mathbb R^3\longrightarrow \mathbb R$, so $J_w(a,b,c)$ is just the transpose of $\nabla w(a,b,c)$.
Therefore:

$$J_{V\circ w}(a,b,c) =  V'\big(w(a,b,c)\big)\cdot 
\left(
\frac{\partial w}{\partial a}(a,b,c),
\frac{\partial w}{\partial b}(a,b,c),
\frac{\partial w}{\partial c}(a,b,c)
\right)$$

Comment: You calculate $V'$ the same way you calculate $f'$ for single variable functions, like $f(x) = cos(x)$. Then you plug $x=w(a,b,c)$ into $V'(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the chain rule should be correct. I've recently used it in multiple Partial Differential Equations exams, with the formula you've given:
$$\dfrac{dV}{dw(a,b,c)} = \dfrac{dV}{da} \dfrac{\partial a}{\partial w} + \dfrac{dV}{db} \dfrac{\partial b}{\partial w}+ \dfrac{dV}{dc} \dfrac{\partial c}{\partial w}$$
Wikipedia also says this is the correct way to apply the chain rule in higher dimensions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions

I'd say check your numerical findings again, or even show it to us, to see where this might have gone wrong.

Comment: This is some arcane way of writing the chain rule for Jacobian/total derivative.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Could you please expand? Or give the non-arcane approach?

Comment: Currently no, because I do not understand your question.

Comment: Maybe this helps:
$$\dfrac{dV}{dw(a,b,c)} = \dfrac{dV}{da} \dfrac{\partial a}{\partial w} + \dfrac{dV}{db} \dfrac{\partial b}{\partial w}+ \dfrac{dV}{dc} \dfrac{\partial c}{\partial w} \iff \\ 
\iff \partial_{w(a,b,c)}V = \partial_aV \partial_wa + \partial_bV \partial_wb + \partial_cV \partial_wc$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following functions:

$$f = f(x,y)$$

$$g = g(f)$$

It's clear that $g$ can be written in terms of $(x,y)$ once the form of $f$ and $g$ is known. Thus using the chain rule,

$$dg = \dfrac{\partial{g}}{\partial{x}} dx + \dfrac{\partial{g}}{\partial{y}} dy$$

Also we can write:

$$\dfrac{\partial{g}}{\partial{x}} = \dfrac{\partial{g}}{\partial{f}} \dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}$$
$$\dfrac{\partial{g}}{\partial{y}} = \dfrac{\partial{g}}{\partial{f}} \dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}$$

Hence:

$$dg = \dfrac{\partial{g}}{\partial{f}}(\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}} dx + \dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}} dy)$$

Finally:

$$\dfrac{dg(f)}{df(x,y)} = \dfrac{\partial{g}}{\partial{f}}(\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}} \dfrac{dx}{df} + \dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}} \dfrac{dy}{df})$$