# Removing parameter when differentiating parametric function gives a different result than direct application of chain rule

Tags: parametric, implicit-differentiation

Consider the function

$$f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$$

If we introduce the variables

$$\begin{align}
r&=x\cos\varphi-y\sin\varphi,\\
u&=y\cos\varphi+x\sin\varphi,
\end{align}$$

we'll get that

$$f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{u^2+r^2}.$$

If we now fix $x$ and use $y$ as a parameter and consider a parametric function $(u(x,y),f(x,y))$ and try to differentiate $f$ with respect to $u$, we'll get:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}u}=\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}y}\bigg/\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}y}=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\bigg/\cos\varphi=\frac{y}{f(x,y)\cos\varphi}.$$

But if we directly express $f$ in terms of $u$ and differentiate the resulting expression, we'll instead get:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}u}=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u}\sqrt{u^2+r^2}=\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+r^2}}=\frac {y\cos\varphi+x\sin\varphi}{f(x,y)}.$$

These two results don't match, but I can't seem to spot the mistake.

So what am I doing wrong here? Why don't the results match?

Comment: I'm not too sure if you can differentiate with respect to $u(x,y)$ in such a way because it is a [multivariable function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2786617/derivative-of-function-with-respect-to-multivariable-function). Also note that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u}r$ should not be zero because clearly $r$ is somewhat dependent on $u$ as $r=\partial_\varphi u$.

Comment: Is it supposed to be `a parametric function $(u(y), r(y))$'? The wording is still strange, but it might make sense that way...

Comment: @Rhys no, it's supposed to be the function $f(u)$, but defined in a parametric way via the parameter $y$, so it describes a curve in 2D space with abscissa being $u$ and ordinate $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is in the second method, where you treat $r$ as constant whereas it still contains the parameter $y.$

You're supposed to differentiate the function $$\sqrt{x^2+\left(\frac{u-x\sin\phi}{\cos\phi}\right)^2}$$ instead.